# Encadenar métodos estaticos y no estaticos en php

Tags: php, sql, orm

Intento hacer mi propio ORM y me estoy basando en Eloquent de Laravel pero tengo un problema
cuando intento encadenar metodos no me funciona bueno en una acción en especifico
Ejemplo

```
 $user = User::where('rol_id', 1)->where('status', 1)->get()
```

en el método estático `where` creo una instancia con

```
 new static;
```

Funciona perfecto solo, pero si encadeno otro where ya no toma el primero y solo se ejecuta el segundo where. Qué puedo hacer para que se ejecuten los 2 o n numero de where??

Este es el código del método

```
public static function where(string $column, string $value, string $value2 = NULL)
{
    $operator = '=';
    $operators = ['=', '<', '>', '<>', '!=', '<=', '>='];
    if (in_array($value, $operators)) {
        $operator = $value;
        $value = $value2;
    }

    $model = new static;
    $model->$column = $value;

    if (strpos($model->sql, 'WHERE') === false) {
        $model->sql .= " WHERE ";
    }
    $model->setColumns();
    if (property_exists($model, 'softDelete') && $model->softDelete  == true) {
        if (strpos($model->sql, "NULL") === false) {
            $model->sql .= " (deleted_at IS NULL) AND ";
        }
    }
    foreach ($model->columns as $column => $value) {
        $model->sql .= $column . " " . $operator . "  ? AND ";
    }

    $model->setSql($model->sql);
    return $model;
}
```

Comment: las preguntas que buscan depuracion deben incluir un codigo de ejemplo minimo verficable, es decir: podrias colocar el codigo del metodo?

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es que creas un nuevo objeto cada vez, aquí una reducción de lo que te pasa

Digamos que tienes una función donde pasas un string como argumento y lo quieres almacenar en un `array` (que es básicamente lo mismo que ir concatenando un where para crear una consulta)

```
class User{
    public $datos =[];

    public static function where($n){
        $model = new static;
        $model->datos[] = $n;
        return $model;
    }
}
$user = User::where("A")->where("B")->where("C")->where("D");
var_dump($user);
```

Resultado:

```
object(User)#1 (1) { ["datos"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "D" } }
```

Como puedes ver, solo existe `D` y es que siempre te quedarás con el último, porque reseteas el objeto al hacer `$model = new static;`

Lo que necesitas es crear un método no estático where para el objeto, y además usar algo como los [métodos mágicos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.magic.php) `__call` y `__callStatic` ya que en PHP no existe sobrecarga de funciones en el sentido tradicional

```
class User{
    public $datos =[];

    private function _where($n){
       //Aquí iría la implementación real de la función
        $this->datos[] = $n;
        return $this;
    }

    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments) {
        return call_user_func(array(new User(), "_".$name),...$arguments);
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        return call_user_func(array('User', "_".$name),...$arguments);
    }
}
$user = User::where("A")->where("B")->where("C")->where("D");
var_dump($user);
```

Resultado

```
bject(User)#1 (1) { ["datos"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "A" [1]=> string(1) "B" [2]=> string(1) "C" [3]=> string(1) "D" } }
```

Comment: comentas que no existe la sobrecarga de funciones pero lo que haces con `__call()` y `__callStatic()` es precisamente [sobrecarga de métodos / funciones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods)

Comment: @Solrac discrepo estimado. La `sobrecarga` es un concepto genérico en la programación, y es la capacidad de llamar con el mismo nombre a 2 implementaciones distintas, donde el punto importante es el `nombre`. Así que a mi parecer la documentación de PHP enreda el concepto y si lees los comentarios de la misma página veras que no soy el único que opina de ese modo.

Comment: @Yussef se puede ajustar el wording para aclarar que "en PHP no existe sobrecarga de funciones en el sentido tradicional" ( o algo parecido ) ->
`Note:
PHP's interpretation of overloading is different than most object-oriented languages. Overloading traditionally provides the ability to have multiple methods with the same name but different quantities and types of arguments.`

Comment: @aloMalbarez ok, me parece muy acertada la modificación que propones

Comment: funcionó hacer eso con call y callstatic pero si meto eso en un bucle el primer where ya no se actualiza con el valor correspondiente a qué se deberá?

Comment: @Francisco dame un ejemplo

Comment: `for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
            $permiso = UserPermit::where('action_id', $i)->where('user_id', 1)->first();
        }` en ese caso el action id no cambia, siempre me regresa el id 1

Comment: pero si solo saco del for y consulto 1 por 1 si funciona perfectamente bien

Comment: Es el mismo error conceptual que tienes en tu pregunta (cuando hacías `$model = new static;`). Estas pisando la variable dentro del for

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el error está en el concepto de la clase, pero también en como estás llamando a tus métodos; me explico:

Considera la clase user:

```
class user {

    public function get() {
        echo 'Si, si... llegaste aquí' . PHP_EOL;

        return $this;
    }

    public static function where() {
        echo 'Estás usando where' . PHP_EOL;
        $instancia = new user();

        return $instancia;
    }
}
```

Esta clase cuenta con un método estático `where()` que crea una instancia de la clase `user` y regresa esa instancia. También cuenta con un método `get()` (no estático) que regresa la instancia sobre la que está operando esa función: `$this`.

Ahora considera este llamado:

```
user::where()::where()->get()->get();
```

El método estático `::where()` está creando una instancia de la clase `user` y está regresando esa instancia, al llamar a `::where()` nuevamente se está creando una segunda instancia de la clase `user` y regresa esta segunda instancia. Ahora estamos trabajando con la segunda instancia de `user` y llamamos al método `->get()`, éste método no crea una nueva instancia, en cambio regresa la misma segunda instancia para que podamos seguir usando el mismo objeto. Al llamar a `get->()` una segunda ocasión estamos trabajando nuevamente sobre la segunda instancia de `user`.

El resultado de este código es:

```
Estás usando where
Estás usando where
Si, si... llegaste aquí
Si, si... llegaste aquí
```

Comment: es correcto, se trabaja con la segunda instancia lo que hace que la cadena sql sea completamente nueva, hay alguna forma de trabajar con una sola instancia para que la cadena sql sea la misma ??

Comment: Para trabajar siempre con la misma instancia debes usar métodos NO estáticos o bien usar métodos estáticos pero pasar la instancia como parámetro y regresarla como respuesta. También recuerda que puedes usar las clases de la siguiente manera `(new user())->get()->get()`

Comment: creo que ya lo solucioné solo generé la instancia por medio de singleton y listo. Gracias

Comment: ahora tengo otro problema :(, cuando hago un foreach siempre me regresa el mismo registro `$actions = Action::where('module_id', 2)->get();
        foreach ($actions as $action) {
            $permission = UserPermit::where('action_id', $action->id)->where('user_id', 1)->first();
        }`

Comment: siempre me regresa el registro con action_id = 1, no se está cambiando el atributo action_id, agregue los metodos __set y __get pero aún así no funciona